# Declare a session variable golbaly to access from DoGet and DoPost in a sevlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet where I need to declare a session which can be acceptable form doGet and doPost both how I should do this?
I have done

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginLogout", urlPatterns = {"/LoginLogout.do"})public class LoginLogout extends HttpServlet {//For Session
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String status = request.getParameter("status");
    System.out.println(status);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        String loginId = request.getParameter("login_id");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        System.out.println(loginId);

        //Inserting value to the Pogo named "newLoginPogo"
        loginData newLoginPogo = new loginData();
        newLoginPogo.setLoginId(loginId);
        newLoginPogo.setPassword(password);

        //Creating a obj of ModelLogin to send the loginId and Password via a method which is in ModelLogin class
        ModelLogin loginBis = new ModelLogin();
        loginData userData = loginBis.checkUser(newLoginPogo);
        String userExist = userData.getUserExist();
        System.out.println(userExist);
        if ("yes".equals(userExist)) {
            System.out.println("In while loop of Servlet");

            String firstName = userData.getFirstName();
            String userId = userData.getUserId();
            boolean IsSu = userData.getIsSu();
            //conveting boolean to string
            String superuser = new Boolean(IsSu).toString();

            //Creating a session 

            session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);
            session.setAttribute(userId, "userId");
            session.setAttribute(superuser, "IsSu");
            //==============================================================================================================
            //If user does exist show the Success Message and forward Dashboard 
            //==============================================================================================================

            //Session for success message
            String succmsg = "Login Successful";
            session.setAttribute("succmsg", succmsg);

            getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ViewPages/dashboard/dashboard.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } //==============================================================================================================
        //If user does not exist show the Error Message  
        //==============================================================================================================
        else if ("no".equals(userExist)) {
            //Session for success message
            System.out.println("inside NO");
            String emsg = "Login Error";
            session.setAttribute("errmsg", emsg);
            getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
        }
        /*
        //===============================================================================================================    
        //code for Logout
        //===============================================================================================================
        String status = request.getParameter("status");
        if ("logout".equals(status)) {
            //clearing the session
            session.invalidate();
            //forwarding to index page
            getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        */
    } finally {
    }
}}
```

But it says

```
Can Not find Symbol
```

in this line HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have session variable in servlet as field. In general - this is kind of common mistake. There will be only one onstance of servlet serving lots of requests, and unless you declare it as single-threaded - the requests would be handled concurrently.

HttpSession will be pre-exist for you in doGet and doPost via request object. Servlet container will guarantee this. So simply obtain reference to the session in doGet/doPost and do whatever you want.

Comment: look at my comment, i edited it, and included a link to an example

Answer (score 0):

What you desire is one of the roles of HTTP session. 
You can look at it as a conversation between the client and the server. 
As long as the "conversation" (HTTP session) is open and alive, you can set variables on the HTTP session, and access them from different requests that will sent on the same session. 
Look at this as some sort of "shared memory" that exists during the "conversation time". 
You can find many examples on how to do that over the internet. 
Here is an example for [session tracking](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html).